# Cannot get access of stored user_id constants

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to call the current users profile in my app. In order to do that I store the users is in the login procedure. I store the value user_id  in my auth.serivice. Then I try to get this key value in the profile page, to display the logged in users data. But I don't really get how to make use of this id. Since Im not coming from another page I cannot use the activatedRoute logic. I thought I just simply have to call the storage and then store the value in my `information` variable. The id that is stored `USER_ID` is a number and the storing is working I see my id there. If I want to call my id in the profile page I get the error that `patchValue is not available for type number`.

auth.service.ts

```
export const USER_ID = 'user_id';  
...
this.user = this.helper.decodeToken(res['access']); // the user id is stored value = 1
```

user.service.ts

```
 // get a user's profile
  getUserDetails(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/${id}/`);
  }
```

profile.page.ts

```
information = null; // store my data here
id: number;  // Id to get the user data from server is a number
...

ngOnInit() {

      this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => { // get the stored user_id 
        this.id.patchValue({ user_id: val}); // store the current userid in id
        console.log(this.id);
      });


  // Get the information from the API
  this.userService.getUserDetails(this.id).subscribe(result => { // get the user data from the server
    this.information = result;
    console.log(result);
    console.log(this.information);
    console.log(this.id);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your auth.service is a Singletown?

If the auth.service, is not loaded in the entire application, provided in app.module, or with providedIn property in Injector, when you change pages, the auth.service will be not loaded or will create another instance.

You can provide in app.module, in providers property.

```
  providers: [ AuthService ]
```

The example with providedIn:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Thats example refers to create a singletown service. Have many ways to do a solution for that problem.

Comment: But that doesn't solve my problem. I can already make the same with the username in the profile page (fetch it from the storage, patchValue). There is more a problem with how can I make use of this id and get my data.

Comment: You problem is in id attribute.

So, change the patchValue to:
`code`
this.id = val;
The id attribute is number, not an object, so put an number into.

Comment: Ok now it los for ` this.storage.get(USER_ID).then(val => {
        this.id = val;
        console.log(this.id);
      });
` the actual id in my console and its a number. But the call that takes the id, the id is undefined, like that => `http://1234/users/undefined/`

Comment: What returns in this function? In the `val` variable? Comes an object? Or the real id? If was an object, you have to use `this.id = val.user_id`

Comment: for both of this logs ` console.log(this.id);
        console.log(val);` I get a number back, a pure number like `13`, so sadly it doesn't work with `this.id = val.user_id `

Comment: The result of the storage comes from an API?

If yes, your subscribe have to be inside the then function, because a promise is a async function.

Try to put the getUserDetais inside the then of the first result.

Asyncronous calls don't stop the thread, so when the compiler starts the promise, will continue the execution of the rest code.